# Ext4 disk partitions are not visible

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, disk, ext4

I'm a new user of the Linux environment. I have just have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my system and I'm unable to see the disk partition in which I have installed the OS.

Size of the main disk is 100 GB and I want to see it back so that I can save my data in it. Please help. The disk format is ext4.

Comment: Please open a Terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run this command (by pasting it into the Terminal and pressing enter): `df -h; mount; sudo fdisk -l; sudo parted -l` You may be prompted for your password. As you enter it, you won't see any placeholder characters (like *). That's OK--just type it in and press enter. Then select all the text in the Terminal (Edit > Select All), copy it to the clipboard (Edit > Copy), and paste it into your question or into a reply comment.

Answer (score 1):

Open Home Folder, 
In The Sidebar Click on File System, 
Open 'host' folder, 
Your Drive is in front of your eyes ;)
Enjoy Linux!

Answer (score 0):

You can start the Disk Utility (open Dash and write `Disk Utility`) which gives full access to the disk partitions.

The program name is `palimpsest` (if you run it from the command line).

Answer (score 0):

When you open the File Manager, which is called the Home Folder in the Launcher of 11.10 you will see a panel on the left. All the folders under **Computer** from Home to Rubbish Bin represent what is on your hard disk in the Ubuntu ext4 partition.

Under **Devices** you will see other partitions including those with other operating systems on them.

While the File Manager is open move the pointer to the top left of the panel. Some menu options will appear. Select Go and click on Computer. There you will also see an icon for your hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

When are the partitions invisible? Note that by default, you're unable to see extX-partitions in Microsoft Windows. You'll need a special viewer for that. You can download one [here](http://www.soluvas.com/read-browse-explore-open-ext2-ext3-ext4-partition-filesystem-from-windows-7/).